# How do list instances with specific label using Compute API in GCP?

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, instance

I am using the GCP Compute API Method for Python and trying to get a list of all instances with a specific tag. The syntax for listing instances is:

> service.instances().list(project=project, zone=zone).execute()

However whenever I add *filter=my-label:label* or anything similar I am getting an error.
Wondering if anyone else was able to get a list and if so how?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this syntax:

```
request = service.instances().list(project=project, zone=zone, filter='labels.my-label=my-value')
```

Make sure at least one instance match the filtering criteria, otherwise `response[items]` will not be defined.

Comment: Yeah, that did it! Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @Beembo, Glad I could help. Thanks for the feedback. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers